# Facing issues while integrating REDUX DEVTOOLS in REACT program

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was using redux developer tools in my application and When I opened the redux dev tools for having a look at the states there it showed undefined whereas my application is working perfectly fine. I think there is some mistake in my store code. I am attaching the code below.

```
import {legacy_createStore , composer} from 'redux'

import reducer from './reducerFn'

const composerEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSER__ || composer ;

export const store = legacy_createStore(reducer , composerEnhancer());
```

I have tried everything I searched on web. Could you please pin point the error in my code.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this error. And I ll tryna keep it more decriptive next time.

Comment: No I do not know how to fix it. Do it next time _and_ this time please. Questions here are not _supposed_ to be one-off-throw-away-after. The goal of this site is to provide long-term value to communities of developers.

Comment: There's a typo, redux exports a `compose` function, not a `composer` function. Voting to close as "Unreproducible or caused by typo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It should be compose in place of composer everywhere.

```js
import {legacy_createStore , compose} from 'redux'

import reducer from './reducerFn'

const composerEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose ;

export const store = legacy_createStore(reducer , composerEnhancer());
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a direct answer: you're using an outdated style of Redux setup code there.  Today you *should* be using the `configureStore` API from our official Redux Toolkit package, which already does all of that Redux DevTools setup work for you automatically.

All you need is:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import rootReducer from "./reducerFn";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})
```

and that will do the Redux DevTools setup for you:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#creating-the-redux-store
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-configurestore

Comment: Yeah I know but the task is to use this one only... But thanks anyways.